# I need specific output based on the input in the php form

Tags: php, html

I need to display particular text based on the user's input
for eg: If the user types in orange, i need the output to be Oranges are good for healt,
if the input is apples, i want it to be apples are red.

Sorry if the question is too basic, i am very new to php.

My html code:

```
<form method="post" action="tips.php" style="float: left; margin: 25px; font-size:300%;">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  <center><input type="submit"></div></center>
</form>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
$t = echo $_POST["name"];

if ($t =="Apple") {
  echo "Apples are red";
} 
if ($t =="Oranges") {
  echo "Oranges are good";
} 

?>
```

Comment: You do not need the `echo` there. [It is used for outputting text.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) Just set the variable `$t` to the POST value `$t = $_POST['name']`.

Comment: $t = echo $_POST["name"]; => $t = $_POST["name"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` function return type is void and logically you don't need echo when accessing data from `$_POST`

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // set correct mime-type

$name = $_POST["name"];

if ($name =="Apple") {
  echo "Apples are red";
} 
elif ($name =="Oranges") {
  echo "Oranges are good";
}
else {
  // Always send back some response:
  echo "I did not recognize your input.";
}
```

Comment: You should add a `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` statement prior to the first `if` statement and explain why.

Comment: POST or GET, it's up to him to modify? I can put this into an if statement but that would be mean modifying the context of his question. Really not sure why we need to set that explicitly tho.

Comment: What is being sent back is something that is *not* a valid HTML document but rather just plain text. Without the explicit header statement I have suggested, PHP will send back a header with a mime-type of 'text/html', which does not match the actual output. It's okay to also point out other errors in the code, such as the OP should be using an if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `echo` returns void (nothing is being returned) which means you assigned your `$t` to nothing. Remove the `echo` from the variable assignment.

`$t = $_POST['name'];`

Also it is better to use understandable variable names, the letter t doesn't say much to me, instead use for example `$name` as [@Ashu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8155208/ashu) suggested.

`$name = $_POST['name'];`

Also you are checking the same value multiple times, the [`switch` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is better for that.

```
switch($name) {
  case 'Apple':
    echo "Apples are red";
    break;
  case 'Oranges':
    echo "Oranges are good";
    break;
  default:
    echo "You entered something else";
    break;
}
```